# gdallocationinfo behaviour from windows to linux

Tags: gdal, netcdf

I used NETCDF for many years on windows (using GDAL ) now recently i
tried on Linux for netcdf data value.I  used gdallocationinfo on windows for retrieving
atmospheric parameter value from netcdf file. same i tried on Linux
but i am getting a fill value -999 for some files.GDAL 1.11 is used in both the
systems.On windows proper value is resulted for both the example files mentioned below from the file.Though same syntax is used on LINUX for one file (aerosol optical depth) it is working and for the other different result is observed.
`gdallocationinfo -geoloc -valonly NETCDF:g4.timeAvgMap.MOD08_D3_6_1_Water_Vapor_Near_Infrared_Clear_Mean.20190514-20190514.180W_90S_180E_90N.nc:MOD08_D3_6_1_Water_Vapor_Near_Infrared_Clear_Mean 75.2 35.2` 
is resulting different
way.But i got a proper result (on linux) for aerosol optical depth variable

```
gdallocationinfo -geoloc -valonly NETCDF:g4.timeAvgMap.MOD08_D3_6_1_Aerosol_Optical_Depth_Land_Ocean_Mean.20190514-20190514.180W_90S_180E_90N:MOD08_D3_6_1_Aerosol_Optical_Depth_Land_Ocean_Mean 75.2 35.2
```

if variable name is wrong then it should give message, but output is coming as the constant value of -9999.

Comment: Unless you provide example data to replicate this issue, this is going to be hard to help you with. I highly recommend you do not use severely outdated software from half a decade ago.

Comment: True bugmenot, but already existing other softwares required that old version of GDAL.I can provide you files but how to add netcdf files , i am new to upload files in gis stack exchange.

Comment: I have downloaded from this url: https://giovanni.gsfc.nasa.gov/giovanni/#service=TmAvMp&starttime=2019-05-14T00:00:00Z&endtime=2019-05-14T23:59:59Z&data=MOD08_D3_6_1_Aerosol_Optical_Depth_Land_Ocean_Mean%2CMOD08_D3_6_1_Water_Vapor_Near_Infrared_Clear_Mean&dataKeyword=MOD08_D3

Comment: You could upload a file to https://transfer.sh/ and share the resulting URL.

Comment: please find data at https://transfer.sh/6ktOh/g4.timeAvgMap.MOD08_D3_6_1_Aerosol_Optical_Depth_Land_Ocean_Mean.20190514-20190514.180W_90S_180E_90N.nc
https://transfer.sh/t6Qqr/g4.timeAvgMap.MOD08_D3_6_1_Water_Vapor_Near_Infrared_Clear_Mean.20190514-20190514.180W_90S_180E_90N.nc

Comment: Are you sure that gdallocationinfo is supposed to work without the ".nc" part of the filename? I get the value 0.813000038615428 if I add that, on Archinux with 2.4.1.

Comment: No , gdal requires .nc extension. i updated my question.thank you.the name contains ".nc". if the file displayed in arcmap , values are seen.But on Linux with gdal its not giving.

Comment: I tried to copy file by using gdal_translate -of NETCDF F:\sourcefolder\***.nc  F:\targetfolder\***.nc  on RHEL system. then i checked same syntax of gdallocationinfo for F:\sourcefolder\***.nc . then it is showing values properly. May i know the reason please.But file size is three times of input.